# Does a newly elected Member of Parliment in an Australian State need to resign from their prior commitments?

Tags: election, government, australia

Queensland is about to have a [State Election](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queensland_state_election,_2015).

For an individual to put themself forward as a candidate, they need either [the support of 6 enrolled voters or the support of a registered party](http://www.ecq.qld.gov.au/2015QLD.aspx?id=11892).

If the candidate currently runs a private company, or is employed full-time, etc... what is practically required of them in relation to these existing commitments in order to fulfill their duties as a new Member of Parliament?

A day in the life of an MP typically [looks like this](http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/House_of_Representatives/Powers_practice_and_procedure/00_-_Infosheets/Infosheet_15_-_The_work_of_a_Member_of_Parliament). The candidate's life will probably get busier than their life prior to being an MP, so do they need to resign from their job or have other people run their company full-time etc?

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely an expectation that you'll dedicate your full efforts to being an MP. I'm not aware of any obvious statutory provisions requiring you to resign from jobs (apart from roles in the public service), but given how hard one must work to become an MP, and how hard one must work while an MP, I doubt any successful candidate would choose not to quit their previous job. In the event that someone did decide to do that and it was impacting on their parliamentary responsibilities, firstly their party would probably find a way to punish them, but I also wouldn't be surprised if there was a way for the House to punish them for contempt or similar.

A number of MPs do maintain side positions like company directorships and so on, though.

Answer (score 0):

In short, No. In Victoria there was a controversy when Frankston MP Geoff Shaw was caught out using his Taxpayer-Subsidised vehicle to carry out business at a hardware shop that he owned and for a while he commanded power in the Victorian Legislative Assembly with the current government needing his support to bring through legislation.

There is no requirement of an MP to sacrifice any previous commitments but it would be quite hard to carry out the duty of being an MP whilst also continuing to uphold their prior commitments.

Comment: Links to a/n article would be helpful, or perhaps the law itself stating this.